# Python Logging - writes the logs:not in correct file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I am using the logging module in python,

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logging.basicConfig(
handlers=[RotatingFileHandler('test.log', maxBytes=25 * 1024 * 1024, backupCount=3)],
level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s')

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and I used `logger.info(<messages>)` function to write the logs.

After very long logs are generated, multiple log files are created as `test.log`, `test.log.1`, `test.log.2`, `test.log.3`

`test.log` will contains the recent logs

when I am checking the logs today, the log is stopped at two days before. But the program is running, and I found accidentally, that the recent/new logs are saving in the `test.log.1` file instead of `test.log`

Usually, the recent/new logs are saving in the `test.log` but here it is saving in `test.log.1`

So, I checked the files size using `du -sh *` command

```
4.0K test.log
25M  test.log.1
26M  test.log.2
26M  test.log.3
```

the `test.log.1` is already have 25MB of data, it is supposed to start saving the new logs in the `test.log`

Could you please let me know why this behaviour, and how to solve this

thanks

Comment: Do you use multithreaded or multiprocessing in application?

Comment: @NonameNoSurname, i am using multithreading in my program

Comment: It can sometimes cause unexpected behavior in file handling.

Comment: @NonameNoSurname, ok got it, when we use threading, this might happens

Comment: Can you describe how resolve problem? I think it was intresting

Comment: @NonameNoSurname, I didnt solve this yet, I cant remove the threading from my program